# maven install failed"generics not supported"

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using embedded jetty server to build a war, I ran maven clean through eclipse, then maven install. I get a bunch of "not supported" errors

```
\RoleDao.java:[86,13] generics are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
        public List<Role> findAllRoles()

UserAuth.java:[44,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that you are defining language level of 1.3. This is the default of older versions of the Maven Compiler Plugin like 2.0. Upgrade to a newer version like 2.3.2 or even the latest 2.5.1 and the default will be 1.5 and it should work just fine.

And while you are at it also upgrade to the latest version of Maven (3.0.4) so that these newer versions of the Maven Compiler Plugin are the default.

Comment: I've run into a similar problem using Maven 3.0.4 and it appears to be picking up -source 1.3 as the default. To resolve, I had to specify the compiler plugin source as in Tomasz's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is problem with defaults as Manfred pointed. To get rid of this nasty error you can upgrade maven version, maven-compiler-plugin version or configure version in you pom.xml

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

value from  `source` is then passed to compiler as -source argument, to ind out what values are accepted, check this page [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and search for   **-source *release***